# Making list from the data class foreach method

Tags: kotlin

I got every element from the Class changed into the ArrayList using

```
fun getRepos() {
            serviceGit.fetchrepo(object : Callback2 {
                override fun repositoryResult(result: ArrayList<RepositoryResponseItem>) {
                }
            }
            )
        }
```

I would like to iterate all elements from the list, but I cannot use the result.

My idea:

```
for (i in 0 until result.length ){
      if (myElementINeed == i){
mapOf(name to i) 
}
      if (my2ElementINeed == i){
mapOf(photo to i) 
}
            }
```

Name, photo I get from interfaces.

Questions:

1. How to fix to allow using the result in that case?
2. How to implement elements I need from the interface like name, photo?
3. Have you got any idea how to do it better, maybe use forEach and map, cuz these ifs aren't optimal in my opinion, cuz what if I have 50 elements?

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  What do you want _from_ the iteration?  (Right now the code constructs a couple of single-element maps, but immediately discards them.)

Comment: I would like to use map on the list to create new object "newrepo" using every element in the list and next return the result using callback.